# Ionic2: How to package external modules including the css?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I am just learning Ionic2, and trying to include the first of an external module, in this case [Ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/index.php).

Following the instructions [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/index.php), I've installed the node package, so I have the following in my package.json

```
"ag-grid": "^4.2.7",
"ag-grid-ng2": "^4.2.2",
```

I have imported into the test .ts file and included the directive ..

```
...
import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main'
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid/main'

@Component({
   directives: [AgGridNg2],
   templateUrl: 'build/pages/aggrid-page/aggrid-page.html'
})
export class AgGridPage {
   public data: Array<GridRow>;
   public columnDefs;
   public gridOptions: any;
   public showToolPanel;
   ...
```

This is all I have done, and somehow the AgGrid *does* appear in the final `app.bundle.js`, eg in `app.bundle.js` I see

```
var AgGridNg2 = (function () {
function AgGridNg2(elementDef) {
    var _this = this;
    this.elementDef = elementDef;
    // not intended for user to interact with. so putting _ in so if user gets reference
 ...
```

as well as lot of other AgGrid related stuff.

My first question is **how does this get here?**

I don't see any reference to it in the main Ionic gulp file. Does `browserfy` add it after seeing the references in my ts file as shown below?

```
....
import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main'
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid/main'

@Component({
    directives: [AgGridNg2],
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/aggrid-page/aggrid-page.html'
 })
...
```

The next question is **how to package the css files?**

The ag documentation says to link to the files..

```
<link href="node_modules/ag-grid/styles/ag-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="node_modules/ag-grid/styles/theme-fresh.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but these are not found when I add it to the `index.html`. The grid does need them, as is does not display until I do have them included, which I did by adding them to a temp folder under the build folder, and linking to them there, at which stage the grid then displayed correctly.

So wondering how to package them (does css end up in `app.bundle.js` too), and **then reference them?**

Thanks in advance for any pointers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question is how does this get here?

Just like you said,

The `import` statement tells the system it can get both `AgGridNg2` and `GridOptions` components from a module named `ag-grid-ng2/main` and `ag-grid/main`. The module name (AKA module id) is often the same as the filename without its extension.

So then [ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript) **transpile** and **bundle** the sources and that's why you can see them in your `app.bundle.js`.

> The next question is how to package the css files?

I don't really know if there's an *official way to do that* but I prefer to do it by creating a new folder in my `/app/theme` folder called *plugins* and then adding a new file for each plugin with `.scss`extension, and then including them in the `app.core.scss`.

The way it works is pretty similar to what we see in the previous question. In your `gulpfile.js` you will see a task called *sass* which is executed when any `.scss` is changed:

```
gulpWatch('app/**/*.scss', function(){ gulp.start('sass'); });
```

So [ionic-gulp-sass-build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-gulp-sass-build) will compile your `scss` styles into `css`.

Finally, you can see in your `/www/index.html` the result of that task (so your compiled styles) being imported:

```
<link ios-href="build/css/app.ios.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link md-href="build/css/app.md.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link wp-href="build/css/app.wp.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you for that advice. I tried all that (for the css) and worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)